# How to know the domain for a WiFi 802.1x / WPA3-enterprise certificate?

Tags: wireless-networking, android, certificate, wpa2

I'm on a location that has a 802.1x / WPA3-Enterprise WiFi connection using PEAP / MSCHAPv2 authentication. I only know the identity (username) and password.

I can connect with all my devices: my Macbook, an older Android phone, my iPad. Except my Android 11 phone also requires a "domain":

[image: Android 11 requires a domain]

Note that all other devices don't require this, they can connect just fine with only the identity and password.

I am completely clueless what to fill in here. There is no system administrator or IT I can contact. Since the other devices can connect without any domain, I figured it must somehow be possible to derive the domain from the certificate.

If I look into recent certificates on my MacOS it shows a 'Vigor Router' certificate for this WiFi connection. If I look into the certificate details, I see this:

[image: Certificate details on MacOS]

I don't see any domain name. I found sometimes a domain is entered into the Common Name (CN) field, which is `Vigor Router` in this case. If I fill that in for domain it doesn't work. Also tried `draytek.com` and `www.draytek.com` in case it's some standard certificate setting (this Vigor Router is from Drayek) but no go either.

Upon searching I also noticed it may be the 'FQDN' field but I don't see any such field (or anything that looks like a domain) in the certificate details.
Other workarounds I found involved installing a different certificate on the 'RADIUS server' but I am clueless as to what that is, and more importantly I don't have access to any router or server here. I can only connect as a regular network user.

Is there a way to figure out what I have to specify for 'domain' to connect on Android 11?

P.S. I realize this was changed since Android 11 for security reasons, and that the way the other devices do it is actually insecure. For practical means and purposes, in this particular case I don't care about security - I just need to connect no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed find the correct domain in the network's certificate (PEAP uses regular TLS certificates that would have it either in the CN or SAN), but having the device automatically take it from there would rather defeat the whole point of domain verification.

The reason other devices are able to connect isn't because they derive the domain from the certificate – it's because they don't bother looking for it in the first place. (Android did no verification, iOS remembers the exact certificate.) Which, unfortunately, implies that the certificate might not even *have* a valid domain in the first place.

(But if it had one, it'd be on the "server" certificate, not on the "root" certificate.)

However, domain verification is only truly needed when the network is using a *public* TLS CA (e.g. DigiCert or such) for its certificates.

Your network seems to be using an internal CA, which (even if it's a garbage CA autogenerated by the router) still makes it a quite different situation – as long as random people cannot obtain TLS certificates from it, you're fine with trusting the CA as a whole.

You should be able to export the CA root certificate from macOS and import it into your Android device as a "Wi-Fi CA". It should then show up as an option instead of your current "Use system CAs" selection, and choosing it should make the Domain field optional.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried exporting the self-signed root CA from macOS, I've got a .cer file (also converted that to .pem and .crt just in case), copied those to my Android phone, and tried to import it there as a WiFi CA. Unfortunately it says "private key required to import certificate" (tried all 3 formats). Am I exporting it incorrectly? I just right-click the Vigor Router certificate in macOS' Keychain Access app and choose Export Certificate (I don't see any options related to keys or encryption there). Or is it somehow automatically using some private key from my macOS environment?

Comment: Ah right, current Android seems to have separate "CA cert" and "Wi-Fi cert" options – in this case you want to select the former instead.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to add I tried that as well, but unfortunately I get the same message there too: private key required to install certificate. Can I somehow export it differently, or convert it to a different format, so that doesn't require a private key on Android 11? I don't have the private key as far as I know (I assume only the router will have it) but since macOS can install the CA, logically Android should be able to install it as well?

Comment: The "CA certificate" option should not require a private key. I'm pretty sure I've installed CAs from .crt files without a user keypair included. It could be that Android is not recognizing the router's certificate as a CA because it's not actually marked as one through its extensions (being self-signed only kind of makes it a CA, but it's got the extension fields of a TLS end-host certificate).

Comment: Hmm yes upon some more reading, I'd expect the same. But somehow it keeps giving the same message. Any idea if I can somehow save or export the router's CA differently, so that I can import it on Android without requiring a private key? I guess there's no way to tell Android "look, just import and accept it, regardless if I have the matching private key or not"?

Comment: Android is not asking for the CA's private key here – it's not understanding that you're in fact trying to import _a CA_ in the first place. It expects a private key because it thinks you're importing a "user" certificate. (My Android 12 phone seems to allow importing Wi-Fi CA certificates from the "PEAP details" screen, but your screenshot doesn't look like it has the selection active at all.)

Comment: Right, thanks, I see.. Maybe upgrading to Android 12 would help then. But I have a Pixel 4A and as far as I can tell I have no option to upgrade to Android 12. I guess there is no way to modify the CA somehow to make Android 11 understand it's a root CA rather than a user CA? During my search I also found this: https://cutt.ly/QXObVgO so I guess the missing `CA:TRUE` field is the problem. Exporting the .cer to text and somehow regenerating a new .cer from that (with `CA:TRUE`) is probably not possible?